# ssis package configuration and deployment

Tags: deployment, package, configuration-files, ssis-2012

what is difference between SSIS package configuration and package deployment? what is the difference between 2008 package configuration and 2012 package configuration and also deployment. After creating a package what steps should follow for deploy a SSIS package? what configuration company uses?

Answer (score 1):

**Package configuration** - This is to make your package `dynamic` like instead of making your connection manager with static values you can pass them dynamically. You can get the dynamic values from a file or table or environment variables or registry entry. This is `done during Development phase`.

**Package deployment** - This is done once your package development is complete. You will not run your package always by opening the BIDS/Data Tool. For that, you need to deploy the packages to some location like to a File path or to a database. You can access/call the packages from the deployed location using a job or command.

**2008 vs 2012+**

**Configuration:** In 2012 or higher, you have extra feature like `Project level Connection manger, parameters` those can be accessed by all the packages with in that project. If any changes is required in connection, you can change it in one place instead of going each.

**Deployment:** 2012 or hogher, there is a new feature called `project deployment model`. A new database called SSIDB is created in database engine of the SQL Server. There are lot of feature available like Environments, Folder level Securiy, View logs through reports etc.

More information available in MSDN.

Refer:
[SSIS Catalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479588.aspx)